# Flutter app stuck after "Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk... 950ms"

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Everytime I run my flutter app, it just gets stuck after

```
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...          950ms.
```

I've tried:
flutter clean, flutter run
install the app-debug.apk manually and launch - still won't launch.

When ever it installs, the app on the emulator just opens up for half a second and closes again, but continues to run in the background. I then try to open it and it gives me a message : " 'app' keeps closing".

I do get this when i run the app, don't know if its causing this error:

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\rithw\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.6.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             41.6s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...          950ms
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

I always have to ctrl+C it and end it after 15 minutes of waiting.
No clue what to do.

Comment: Can you share the code that you need init before run MyApp?

Comment: @SangPhạm here is the code:



```Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final _ = await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp(sharedPreferences));
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}```

Comment: You should wrap the code by try-catch (Firebase can cause the app to hang)

Comment: After trying some print statements for logging i found out the main function isn't even starting.